# flaky jobs on heroku using sidekiq/redis

Tags: heroku, redis, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6, sidekiq-cron

We have been having issues with flaky jobs recently on heroku using sidekiq and redis. We are using sidekiq-cron, and whenever testing locally all our jobs execute fine and without issue on-schedule. It seems however, that we have issues with jobs occassionally not running overnight and when i check the cron tab in our sidekiq web viewer it says "no scheduled jobs were found". If i repush our master branch (empty commit) and re-deploy, the schedule tab comes back in web view and everything then starts running again. In our heroku metrics, I have noticed that, overnight, our sidekiq worker has been running at about 180% of its max memory capacity. could this be causing these intermittent job issues we are seeing where things "just dont run"?. Im at a loss for what to do here since the i havent seen any errors other than customers saying intermittently that they arent getting notification emails. I have just scaled our worker dyno for sidekiq from 1-2 and am hoping that fixes things as we are running a fairly large amount of jobs overnight.